# Cheap way to keep parameter matrices orthogonal during optimization?

Tags: linear-solver, nonlinear-equations

TLDR; I can keep matrix variables approximately orthogonal by taking a single gradient step in the direction of "effective rank" of matrix at each step of iterative solver, is there a more effective method with similar cost?

---

I have an iterative solver that's minimizing a problem over $d\times d$ matrices of the form $\operatorname{argmin}_W\|f(WX)-Y\|_2^F$ with $f$ a pointwise nonlinear function like $\tanh$. I solve this by performing gradient descent over $W$ but I'm interested finding a solution over orthogonal matrices.

I could orthogonalize the matrix at each step, but QR step is too expensive, my budget is a few $d\times d$ matmuls, can anyone recommend a method to use here?

My approach so far has been to notice that the following quantity of a matrix is maximized when the matrix is orthogonal, so I insert a single step in the gradient direction of $J$ at each step of the solver.

$$J(X)=\frac{\|X\|_F^4}{\|XX^T\|_F^2}$$

This eventually makes my matrices orthogonal ([code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/119LO_88IJx0RyHQr_THEVQyR9iTv8755#scrollTo=p7NqVnlGnS86)), but I don't know the length of the step to take, so I have to tune that separately.

Is there a better way?

Comment: One way to do this is consider this as an optimization problem on the manifold of orthogonal matrices then adapt your gradient, line search, hessian, etc. to the corresponding structure on the manifold so each step satisfies te orthogonal constraint by construction. c.f. https://press.princeton.edu/absil. I believe that this method typically has better convergence properties than projecting each step, but the line searches are more expensive.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem

Comment: Or https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2022.0576

Comment: @whpowell96 Optimization on matrix manifolds is a good idea, but I am not sure it will solve OP's problem. Indeed, one of the 'ingredients' you need to implement optimization on manifolds is the *retraction*, i.e., a way to take the updated point $x_k+d_k$ (obtained starting from point $x_k$ on the manifold and updating along a direction $d_k$ on the tangent space) and projecting it back onto the manifold. And as far as I know for the manifold of orthogonal matrices the standard way to do it is the QR factorization.

Comment: @NNN by the way, and also for whpowell96: please write answers rather than comments to suggest solutions to the problem. This discussion would be much easier to follow for readers if my comment above was a comment on whpowell's answer, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is something related in:

*Bujanović, Zvonimir; Kressner, Daniel; Schröder, Christian*, [**Iterative refinement of Schur decompositions**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11075-022-01327-6), Numer. Algorithms 92, No. 1, 247-267 (2023). [ZBL1507.65076](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1507.65076).

They iteratively refine Schur decompositions, which also requires efficient orthogonalization. In section 2.2.2 they describe an orthogonalization by Newton-Schulz iteration:

$Q_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}Q_k (3I - Q_k^HQ_k)$

This is similar to your original solution with the gradient, but does not require tuning a step.

Comment: oh, that's what I was looking for! I thought of deriving it myself, but don't really have a good system for doing 2nd derivative w.r.t. to a matrix, so many indices to keep track of

Answer (score 0):

It appears a method based on Householder reflectors ([background](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node128.html)) is used in PyTorch for their orthogonal parameterization [link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/cb812c9832a3cc7f826c2c08ab1e14eefb13c14c/torch/nn/utils/parametrizations.py#L95-L102)

project original (X) to orthogonal space (Q) at each step:

[image]

Using function [householder_product](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.householder_product.html)

Comment: I don't understand the details from your description. Does Pytorch perform QR factorization with Householder reflectors at each step? Or does it use the Householder vectors as a parametrization and optimizes over their entries? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You keep "raw parameterization" $X$ which is unrestricted but you view it through $f(X)$ which gives the orthogonal version above. You can't directly modify $f(X)$, but that's not needed because all the updating is done during gradient descent, which backpropagates through $f$ so that the raw representation $X$ gets updated properly